# openssl x509 gives nondeterministic results

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I generated `prv.pem` with:

```
(step 1)
openssl genrsa -out prv.pem 2048
```

Then I generated `csr.pem` with:

```
(step 2)
openssl req -new -inform PEM -key prv.pem -out csr.pem
```

Then finally I'm able to generate `crt.pem` with:

```
(step 3)
openssl x509 -req -in csr.pem -signkey prv.pem -out crt.pem
```

I noticed that repeating step 2 always writes the exact same sequence (deterministically) of output bytes into `csr.pem`.

I noticed that repeating step 3 writes *nondeterministic* results into `crt.pem`.

- **Why is step 3 nondeterministic?**
- **Is there an additional parameter I can provide to `openssl x509 ...` that would cause the output to be deterministic?**

Comment: `openssl genrsa 2048` doesn't generate a `prv.pem` so please give the **exact** commands you used so that we may reproduce your results.

Comment: Anyway, there are two fields that are likely to differ depending on your configuration: 1) the serial number, and 2) the validity dates.

Comment: Hi @PresidentJamesK.Polk I updated with the exact command! Your mention of the serial number and validity dates sounds on target - do you know how I can specify these? (And overall remove all non-determinism?)

Comment: the `x509` command has two options, `-set_serial` and `-preserve_dates` that should help, but the `-preserve_dates` options implies that it will preserve the validity dates in the CSR, but a CSR doesn't have any. So I don't know how to do that.